# Springs at an angle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, forces, spring

I'm trying to find the equation of motion for the following system:

[image]

This is how I proceeded:

Let's call the length of the hypotenuse $s$. Then,

$$F = 2 \sin{\theta}\cdot-k(s - l_o) = -2kx \frac{s-l_o}{\sqrt{x^2 + l^2}}$$

$$ F= -\frac{2kx}{\sqrt{x^2 + l^2}}\Big( \sqrt{x^2 + l^2} - l_o\Big) = -2kx\Big( 1 - \frac{l_o}{\sqrt{x^2 + l^2}}\Big)$$

$$F = -2kx\Big( 1 - \frac{l_o}{\sqrt{x^2 + (l_o +d)^2}}\Big)$$

At this point, for the case where $d= 0$ I just used Taylor expanision to get $F = -k x^3 / l^2$. But I'm not sure how to proceed from this point.

I tried doing,

$$F = -2kx\Big( 1 - l_o \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{(l_o + d)^2} + 1}}\Big)$$

and then using Taylor expansion for the 1 / sqrt term but that way I get something like

$$F = -2kx\Big( 1 - l_o\big(1 - \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{x^2}{(l_o + d)^2}\big)\Big)$$

$$F = -2kx + 2kxl_o - \frac{kx^3l_o}{(l_o + d)^2}$$

(which doesn't even have correct units) while I should really be getting$$F = -\frac{2kd}{(l_o + d)}x - \frac{kl_o}{(l_o + d)^3}x^3$$

EDIT: The mass is constrained to move in the x direction only.

Comment: In the problem is the motion of the mass constrained to the x direction only or is it free to move in 2 dimensions?

Comment: x direction only. Sorry I'll update the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your formula:

$F=−2kx(1−l_o \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+(l_0+d)^2}} )$

is correct.

Now, for the Taylor expansion, taking only leading terms (for small x), you get:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+(l_0+d)^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(l_0+d)^2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{(l_0+d)^2}+1}}\approx\frac{1}{(l_0+d)}(1-\frac{1}{2}\frac{x^2}{(l_0+d)^2})$

Note you have to get your expression to the form $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+y}}$ in order to use $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+y}}\approx1-y/2$, for $y<<1$. This was the origin of your unit error, which was easy to backtrack because of that.

From here you can easily get the expected answer.